# Angular Cannot assign to read only property 'offsetTop' of object '[object HTMLImageElement]'

Tags: angular

I try to change position of element in the dom but get this error.
I use elementRef.

Html:

```typescript
<div class="container">
  <div class="original-pdf">
    <pdf-viewer *ngIf="pdfSrc" [(page)]="pageVariable" [show-all]="true" [render-text]="true" [original-size]="true"
      [src]="pdfSrc">
     </pdf-viewer>
     <img #Signature *ngIf="imageExpress" class="signature-image" [src]="imageExpress | safeHtml" cdkDragBoundary=".original-pdf"
     (cdkDragEnded)="onDragEnded($event)" cdkDrag>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```typescript
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
@ViewChild('Signature', {static: false }) Signature: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.openPdf();
    this.openImage();
    setTimeout(() =>{
      console.log(this.Signature.nativeElement.offsetTop);
      this.Signature.nativeElement.offsetTop = 0;
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Comment: Post your console...

Answer (score 6):

From [MDN DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop)

> The HTMLElement.offsetTop read-only property returns the distance of
>   the current element relative to the top of the offsetParent node.

`offsetTop` is read-only property. So that is why you are getting error like this.

```typescript
Angular Cannot assign to read only property 'offsetTop' of object '[object HTMLImageElement]'
```

May be you could able to use the `top` property instead of `offsetTop`

```typescript
this.Signature.nativeElement.style.top = "0px";
```